# Извлечение строк текста из японской новеллы

Tags: python

Пытаюсь извлечь строки с текстом на японском из исходного скрипта в отдельный документ так, чтобы на выходе оставался только текст без кода.

Разобрался, как делать это с файлами на английском, но скрипт отказывается работать, если в файле присутствует японский. Как можно это исправить?

```
import re

with open('99.iet') as source, open ('99.txt', 'w') as destination:
    word = source.read()
    for string in word.split('\n'):
        wert = "".join(re.findall('(^.*text.*$)',string))
        if wert:
            destination.write(wert+'\n')
```

Comment: а файл на японском в какой кодировке сохранен?

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку файла. По-умолчанию для европейских языков используется `utf-8`. Для иероглифических, скорее всего `utf-16` или `utf-32`/ Синтаксис тогда будет следующий: `with open('path\to\file', mode='r', encoding='utf-16') as source`

Comment: Кодировка UTF-8, содержит японский текст и код на английском.

Comment: тогда укажите `encoding='utf-8'` при открытии файла

Comment: import re

with open('99.iet', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as source, open ('99.txt', 'w') as destination:
    word = source.read()
    for string in word.split('\n'):
        wert = "".join(re.findall('(^.*text.*$)',string))
        if wert:
            destination.write(wert+'\n')

Не работает.

Comment: Создаётся пустой файл, скрипт просто не видит нужные строки.

Comment: Во второй функции открытия файла тоже нужно указать кодировку

Comment: Еее, спасибо. Теперь работает.)

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено, спасибо [cauf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201178/cauf) и [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu) за помощь!

```
import re

with open('99.iet', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as source, open ('99.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as destination:
    word = source.read()
    for string in word.split('\n'):
        wert = "".join(re.findall('(^.*text.*$)',string))
        if wert:
            destination.write(wert+'\n')
```